# slow matrix operations compared to R

Tags: f#, mathnet-numerics

The following calculation runs much slower than it does in R:

```
let result = (X.Transpose() * b * X).Inverse() * (X.Transpose() * b) * e // about 4 seconds on my machine
```

or this:

```
let result = (X.Transpose() * b * X).QR().Solve((X.Transpose() * b) * e)
```

where

```
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra

let X = DenseMatrix.init 2000 7 (fun i j -> 1.)
let b = SparseMatrix.ofDiag (vector [for i in 0 .. 1999 do yield 1.])
let e = DenseMatrix.init 2000 1 (fun i j -> 1.)
```

In R however, the same calculation can be achieved via the following which only takes a couple hundred milliseconds:

```
result <- solve(crossprod(X,b*X), crossprod(X,b*e)) // less than 200ms
```

Is there a way I can speed up the F# calculation?

[EDIT]
Btw, SparseMatrix seems to be the bottleneck. When a DenseMatrix is used instead, there seems to be a massive speedup.

Comment: What provider are you using? See also https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/MKL.html

Comment: Intel MKL (x64; revision 11; MKL 2017.0)

Comment: @ChristophRüegg see my comment about sparsematrix.

Comment: Any update here? I am encountering the SparseMatrix bottleneck as well. It'd be nice to have the speed of a dense matrix with the memory footprint of a sparse matrix. Is that too much to ask? ;)